# C++. How to return null pointer instead of function return type?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a function that checks regex and returning `std::vector<int>` according to regex result. I need to check if function fail/success. On success return vector object, on fail `nullptr` to later check `if (somefunc() == nullptr) // do smth`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fail"?  Can't you just return an empty vector? Do you even NEED to use "null"?? Or can't you just add a "status" variable to your function call?  Or have the function RETURN a status, and pass the vector by reference?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Value of return type `std::vector<int>` cannot be `nullptr`.

The most straightforward way in this case is to return `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>` instead - in this case it's possible to return `nullptr`.

Other options:

- throw an exception in case of fail
- use `optional<std::vector<int>>` as return type (either `boost::optional` or `std::optional` if your compiler has this C++17 feature)
- return `bool` parameter and have `std::vector<int>&` as output parameter of function

The best way to go really depends on the use case.
For example, if result vector of size 0 is equivalent to 'fail' - feel free to use this kind of knowledge in your code and just check if return vector is empty to know whether function failed or succeed.

**In my practice I almost always stick to return `optional`** (boost or std, depending on environment restriction).
Such interface is the most clear way to state the fact that 'result can either be present or not'.

To sum up - this is not a problem with the only one right solution.
Possible options are listed above - and it's only a matter of your personal experience and environmental restrictions/convetions - which option to choose.

Comment: It depends on your use case

Comment: Thanks for answer. I dont want to use `boost`. Want to try native methods

Comment: Throw an exception on failure. std::optional is not for failure cases.

Comment: std::optional is available since C++17, no need for Boost.

Comment: The optional type is a nice solution. Output parameters are generally eew.

Comment: @ssteinberg: Exceptions are not for failure cases either. They are for exceptional cases. And a failing regex match is far from exceptional.

Comment: True. Use what fits your conventions.

Comment: @k.v. - Good answer to a poor question.  The REAL issue - as you pointed out - is that returning "null or vector" is probably a Bad Idea in the first place - the OP should really consider a different design, if at all possible.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: depends on the use case.

Comment: Mentioning `std::optional` from C++17 would improve this answer; the OP's compiler may already have this feature, and future searchers are increasingly likely to have it.  Even though this is a C++11 question.  (Also mentioning boost is good)

Answer (score 1):

You could return a `std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>` and check that value, or throw an exception, or check `vector.size() == 0` etc.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different options:

- return a `std::vector<int>*` pointer, optionally wrapped in `std::unique_ptr` for lifetime management. Return `nullptr` on failure.
- pass the `std::vector` by a reference parameter, and then return a `bool` for success/failure.
- throw an exception on failure.
- return a `std::pair<std::vector<int>, bool>`, where the pair's `second` field indicates success/failure.