# How to handle a function that is not guaranteed to return anything?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a class that stores & manages a vector containing a number of objects.

I'm finding myself writing a number of functions similar to the following:

```
Object* ObjectManager::getObject(std::string name){
  for(auto it = object_store.begin(); it != object_store.end(); ++it){
    if(it->isCalled(name))
      return &(*it)
  }
  return nullptr;
}
```

I think I would rather return by reference, as here the caller would have to remember to check for null! Is there a way I can change my design to better handle this?

Comment: I don't see how returning a reference removes the need to check. The caller has to check for *something* otherwise how would they know the search succeeded?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44475976/c-how-to-return-null-pointer-instead-of-function-return-type/44476002#44476002

Comment: `boost::optional` allows reference types.  It may do what you want, but of course you still have to either check whether it's empty explicitly or deal with exceptions if you don't explicitly check.  If it's very unlikely (exceptional, you might say) that the return is empty, then you can throw an exception instead of a normal return and have the function return type be a plain reference.

Comment: Personally I think returning a pointer is optimal in this situation.

Comment: bool foo(T& t) and the boolean return is a flag to know if the object t is valid

Comment: Returning by pointers and checking for null is better than all of the alternatives so far listed. There is nothing wrong with pointers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your alternatives are outlined below

---

Change your API to the following

```
object_manager.execute_if_has_object("something", [](auto& object) {
    use_object(object);
});
```

This API is much easier to use, conveys intent perfectly and removes the thought process of error handling, return types, etc from the user's mind

---

Throw an exception.

```
Object& ObjectManager::getObject(const std::string& name){
  for(auto& object : object_store){
    if(object.isCalled(name))
      return object;
  }

  // throw an exception
  throw std::runtime_error{"Object not found"};
}
```

---

Return a bool, pass the `Object` by reference and get a copy

```
bool ObjectManager::getObject(const std::string& name, Object& object_out){
  for(auto& object : object_store){
    if(object.isCalled(name)) {
      object_out = object;
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

---

Let the user do the finding

```
auto iter = std::find(object_store.begin(), object_store.end(), [&name](auto& element) {
    return element.isCalled(name);
}
if (iter != object_store.end()) { ... }
```

---

Also

1. Pass that string by const reference.  When C++17 is available change that const reference to a `std::string_view`
2. Use range based for loops in this situation, they are a more readable alternative for what you are doing

Comment: When C++17 comes along use `std::optional` if you don't like exceptions :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 Can `std::optional` return references? I thought it returned values?

Comment: @Galik True, but like for containers, you can always use `std::reference_wrapper` or pointers.

Comment: BTW my personal view is throwing an exception is a little extreme unless not finding the item exposes a programming error

Comment: @Galik Yes, but if you don't want to return a pointer, like OP, you can't.

Comment: Well, the burden of checking if an optional result was actually returned from a function will always remain on the caller side. Any of the equivalent alternatives are the same in that: nullable pointer, exception or optional value. They differ in semantics and expression of intent. Exceptions work here when it's unexpected and the program has difficulty continuing normally, the choice between a pointer and optional depends on the finer semantics of the returned object (can it be moved or is it small?). Sometimes a raw pointer is just a tad easier on the syntax.

Comment: @rubenvb I agree, it definitely does depend on the situation

Comment: Your "Return a bool and pass the Object by reference" solution is completely wrong. What you actually did was copying the object out.

Comment: @KevinZ that was the intent,  I listed that in my answer because a lot of old APIs used to do things like that, and when you actually go and use that in real code it should be obvious that what you get is a copy

Answer (score 3):

Look at the design of STL (e.g. `find` function), it is not at all bad to return the iterator your just searched for, and return `.end()` otherwise.

```
auto ObjectManager::getObject(std::string name){
  for(auto it = object_store.begin(); it != object_store.end(); ++it){
    if(it->isCalled(name))
      return it;
  }
  return object_store.end();
}
```

---

More: Of course `object_store.end()` may be inaccessible from outside the class but that is not an excuse, because you can do this (note the more slick code also)

```
auto ObjectManager::getObject(std::string name){
  auto it = object_store.begin();
  while(not it->isCalled(name)) ++it;
  return it;
}
auto ObjectManager::nullObject(){return object_store.end();}
```

Less code is better code. You can use it like this:

```
auto result = *om.getObject("pizza"); // search, not check (if you know what you are doing)
```

or

```
auto it = om.getObject("pizza");
if(it != om.nullObject() ){ ... do something with *it... }
```

or

```
auto it = om.getObject("pizza");
if(it != om.nullObject() ){ ... do something with *it... }
else throw java_like_ridiculous_error("I can't find the object, the universe will collapse and it will jump to another plane of existence");
```

---

Of course at this point it is better to call the functions `findOject` and `noposObject` and also question why not using directly `std::find` on the `object_store` container.

Comment: However, the user must check if the returned iterator is `!= end()` which is similar to checking for null

Comment: @Martin, this is an eternal discussion about exception code vs check and all that. I am not going to get in to it again. Someone either 1) needs to know what he is doing (if you are 100% sure the object is there from some separate logic, you can skip the check) or 2) check. There is no free lunch.

Comment: The standard find algorithms should now really all return an std::optional and the whole checking for end business needs to stop. It's useful as an implementation shortcut (you've just reached end, so just return the iterating iterator), but it fails to express intent properly to people not familiar with the idiom.

Comment: @rubenvb, that is not the way the STL was designed and it won't change, because returning `optional` won't fit with the rest of the STL. In my opinion STL has an exceptionally good design. Besides what is the different between having to knowing the `end()` idiom and having to know how to use `optional`? From an efficiency point of view optional has memory requirements not present in the iterator case, even if the optional value is empty.

Comment: @alfC Well, for one, optional expresses intent more clearly. I know the library wasn't designed like that. That fact doesn't make its current design ideal in light of modern C++.

Comment: @rubenvb, I might agree that the intent is more clear from some novice folk but the cost in the complexity of the design and computational/memory efficiency is terribly steep. This kind of design could be nice, but there is no place for that in a general purpose fundamental library in my opinion. One is always free to implement that at a higher level of abstraction if it is necessary.

Comment: How is std::optional computationally more expensive? It's actually less intensive I'd say, because the "invalid" result doesn't need to be constructed/copied at all, whereas now the iterator is required as a return value. I also stand by the "better expresses intent", even in light of your condescending "novice folk" comment, which is irrelevant.

Comment: @rubenvb, in my computer `sizeof(std::optional<double>)=16`,  `sizeof(double)=8`.

Comment: @rubenvb, Last comment from my part, since it got personal with your comment about me being condescending (with other people apparently): 1) I think condescending is to think that people can never learn the good stuff in the design of STL. 2) I also, see that you are trying to propose a complete alternative to STL, good for you, that means that you walk the walk, it would be great if you succeed, just be aware of the history behind STL.

Answer (score 1):

Solution alternative to exceptions or optional is to implement a "[Null object"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) - which can be used as a regular object, but will "do nothing". Depends on the case, sometimes it can be used as is and does not require to be checked (explicitly) - especially in cases where ignoring the "not found" situation is acceptable.

(the null object can be a static global, so it is also possible to return a reference to it)

Even if a check is needed, an `isNull()` method can be implemented, which returns true for the null object and false for a valid object (or there can be `isValid()` method, etc.).

---

Example:

```
class Object {
public:
    virtual void doSomething();
};

class NullObject: public Object {
public:
    virtual void doSomething() {
        // doing nothing - ignoring the null object
    }
};

class ObjectManager {
public:
    Object& getObject(const std::string& name);
private:
    static NullObject s_nullObject;
};

Object& ObjectManager::getObject(const std::string& name){
  for(auto it = object_store.begin(); it != object_store.end(); ++it){
    if(it->isCalled(name))
      return *it;
  }
  return s_nullObject;
}

ObjectManager mgr;
Object& obj = mgr.getObject(name);
obj.doSomething(); // does nothing if the object is NullObject
                   // (without having to check!)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are already handling the return value properly and your current solution is optimal.

The fact is you can not avoid checking for *something* in order to discover if your *find* operation succeeded. If you throw an exception then your `try{}catch{}` is your check. Also an `exception` should not be used when not finding an item is a legitimate result. If you return a `bool` and use an *out parameter* you have made the situation more complicated to do the same job. Same with returning an *iterator*. A `std::optional` returns *values*.

So IMO you can't *improve* upon returning a *pointer* you can just make the same job more complicated.